Which permissions should or must password-polity-related attributes have to let it work?
I'm not sure what permissions a user needs to several LDAP attributes related to password-policy (ppolicy, PP) in OpenLDAP:
Some of the attributes are read and/or set by the slapo-ppolicy overlay, so it seems that no specific permissions for the attributes involved are needed.
However I'm not so sure about the login process (either local or via SSH):
To emit a warning that the password will expire soon or that the password needs to be changed, which users need to read (or write) the related attributes?
The users involved could be some fixed account (like root) and the user authenticating.
So the attributes in question are:

pwdMustChange
pwdAllowUserChange
pwdChangedTime
pwdReset
shadowLastChange

For example:

Does the use need the right to write the userPassword, i.e. to attrs=userPassword by self write by * auth?
Does the user need permissions to write shadowLastChange, i.e. to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
Does the user need write permissions for pwdChangedTime (when changing the password), i.e. to attrs=pwdHistory,pwdGraceUseTime,pwdChangedTime by self read by * none?

What happens if the permissions are not correct:
Will something fail silently (like pwdChangedTime not being updated or created), or will there be an error logged or output?
So aiming at "minimal rights", which rights are absolutely necessary so that everything still works, and which permissions are recommended?
For example:
Does everybody need to have read rights for shadowLastChange?
